# ColorFunction as an interpolating function in a RegionPlot

Tags: color, interpolation, regions

I would like to fill a region below a curve using shading that represents a function (i.e. not just be filled in one solid color).
Here is a working example.

(*a system of ODEs, parameters and their solver*)

```
eX[X_, Y_] := \[Rho] X - \[Beta] X Y - \[Mu] X
eY[X_, Y_] := \[Beta] X Y - \[Mu] Y 
parms = {\[Beta] -> 0.002 , \[Rho] -> 0.27, \[Mu] -> 0.25  };

sys = {X'[t] == eX[X[t], Y[t]], Y'[t] == eY[X[t], Y[t]],
X[0] == 1000, Y[0] == 1};
tmax = 400;
sol = NDSolve[sys /. parms, {X, Y}, {t, 0, tmax}];
```

(*interpolating functions*)

```
Xfn = Flatten[{X} /. sol];
Yfn = Flatten[{Y} /. sol];
```

(*plot - curve is a sum of the two functions*)

```
RegionPlot[{y < Evaluate[Xfn[[1]][t] + Yfn[[1]][t]]}, {t, 0, 50}, 
{y, 0, 1200}, ColorFunction -> Function[{t, y}, t]]
```

I would like the shading under the curve to change as a function of this ratio:

Yfn/(Xfn+Yfn)

I'm assuming that this means changing "Function[{t,y},t]" in ColorFunction to include the function (above) of the ratio, probably in the place of the first t. However, I just can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

[image: image of curve]

Comment: `ColorFunction -> 
 Function[{t, y}, Yfn[[1]][t]/(Xfn[[1]][t] + Yfn[[1]][t])]` but that doesn't show much details (see also `Plot[Yfn[[1]][t]/(Xfn[[1]][t] + Yfn[[1]][t]), {t, 0, 50}]`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `Blend`. Apologies if I have misunderstood.

```
rp = RegionPlot[{y < Evaluate[Xfn[[1]][t] + Yfn[[1]][t]]}, {t, 0, 
    50}, {y, 0, 1200}, 
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{t, y}, 
     Blend[{Red, Green}, Yfn[[1]][t]/(Xfn[[1]][t] + Yfn[[1]][t])]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False];
f = Plot[1000 Yfn[[1]][t]/(Xfn[[1]][t] + Yfn[[1]][t]) - 1200, {t, 0, 
    50}, ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{t, y}, 
     Blend[{Red, Green}, Yfn[[1]][t]/(Xfn[[1]][t] + Yfn[[1]][t])]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Frame -> True];
Show[rp, f, PlotRange -> {-1200, 1200}, 
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Range[0, 1000, 500]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! that worked wonderfully! Thanks.